# Best place to check if a user is blocked by another

Tags: java, spring-security, domain-driven-design

If I want to introduce the concept of blocked users, where is the most appropriate place to make the check if a user is blocked, without breaking the principles of good design?

Till now, I've been using Spring Security, to annotate the controller methods on whether a particular user has the permissions to do a certain action. With this blocked users thing, it gets a bit more complicated. Should I try to fit this again in the controller (possibly with Spring security again) or this is something which I should let the domain object decide itself?

I guess it'd be better to leave this on the controller leve, but I fear if my controllers won't turn into an if...else mess one day.

Comment: What do you mean by "blocked"?

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to introduce role called "BLOCKED", assign it to all users when they are blocked and annotate all methods that do not allow blocked users to access them with:

```
@PreAuthorize("!hasRole('BLOCKED')")
public void secureMethod();
```

Another approach would be to store blocked status in user database or in some other storage. Then extend the [UserDetailsService](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#tech-userdetailsservice) to return additional user information including the "blocked" flag. And the again use security EL to filter methods that do not allow blocked users to execute them:

```
@PreAuthorize("!principal.blocked")
public void secureMethod();
```

**UPDATE**:

Problem you mentioned in the comments can be approached in some similar way:

```
@PreAuthorize("!#photo.owner.blockedUsers.contains(principal.name)")
public void likePhoto(Photo photo);
```

For any more complex and/or generic rules I would advice to use AOP aspects to keep your code clean from too many ifs.

Comment: Thanks. First approach wouldn't work because blocked users are blocked by certain other users, but not by everyone. The second one looks more  possible, but I still have no concept of a context owner. For example, if I want to block certain people from liking my photos, every time the likePhoto controller method is called, I should make a check if the principal is in the blocked list of the photo.owner. It is kind of tricky